# Why does JPA require a transaction to load entities

Tags: hibernate, jpa

WHY does JPA require a transaction/session to be opened for select type queries, such as loading lazy properties?  Could these not be loaded outside of a transaction?  I understand perfectly why it's required for updating or inserting, but seems like an unnecessary constraint for selects (plus a lot of misery for newbies to lazy loading).

Answer (score 0):

JPA does not require a transaction but an `EntityManager` (Hibernate: `Session`) to do so. That's why the workaround can be done by `OpenEntityManagerInView` (or `OpenSessionInView`) and not `OpenTransactionInView`.

What makes you think you need a transaction? See [here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Querying) for simple example code without transactions.

Comment: The OpenEntityManagerInView starts a second transaction for loading lazy properties.  It's a workaround, exactly, and in my opinion not a great design pattern for handling lazy loads.